# 2nd char array overwriting 1st char array after fread from file

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

Goal is to use C to read data from file (could be text or binary) and then append to an existing string

I have 2 char arrays, one an existing string (s1), and another a string (s2) I'll append the buffer char array (buf) to

```
size_t readCounter = 0;
char buf[16];
char s1[] = "hello ";
char s2[] = ""

while (1) {
    readCounter = fread(buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fp);

    if (readCounter == 0) {
        break;
    }

    strcat(s2, buf);    
}

printf("%s", s1);
printf("%s", s2);
```

Problem:

When I print out s1, it no longer is "hello ", it includes the characters from the file so for some reason the first char array is being overwritten in memory. Why does this happen? How can I resolve this?

Comment: `buf` is never initialized, so you're asking for explosions here when calling `strlen` on it.

Comment: okay i put 16 (size of buffer) in place of strlen(buf)

Comment: It's probably better to avoid magical numbers like that and instead use `sizeof(buf)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
readCounter = fread(buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fp);
```

This is a problem. At this point, `buf` doesn't contain a string, so passing it to `strlen` is an error.

Also:

```
char s2[] = "";
...
strcat(s2, buf);
```

This is not good. When you alllocated `s2`, it pointed to an empty string. So the array was sized to hold an empty string. By passing `s2` to `strcat`, you're trying to append onto it -- but it doesn't have any extra space.

Comment: i see, but what does this have to do with s1 and why is s1 overwritten?

Comment: @user3226932 After you make a mistake like this, you cannot reliably access anything. The compiler is free to optimize assuming you will never do this and once you violate that assumption, all bets are off. Maybe the `strcat` happened to scribble over the memory that `s2` happened to be using at that time. Maybe not.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.  'what does this have to do with s1 and why is s1 overwritten?' what?  s2 and s1 are next to each other, so it's not surprising that overrunning one would blast the other.

Comment: A debugger which can show you the memory of where your `char*` pointers point to will make this problem *immediately* evident.

Comment: ok i've used sizeof(buf), is there a better approach than defining an empty string s2 and appending buf to it?

Comment: @user3226932 Maybe allocate a larger buffer.

Comment: how would a larger buffer help? isn't the whole point of fread to read in certain number of bytes at a time? it gets overwritten on the next fread, i need to append buffer to my final string so I can get the full contents of the file

Comment: Chuckling.... short, succinct, and dead on point. That's a good answer. *"you're trying to append onto it -- but it doesn't have any extra space."* -- poetry `:)`

Comment: @user3226932 Right, so maybe allocate a larger buffer for that final string? `char s2[] = "";` allocates only a very small array. You need a bigger one. (Or perhaps make your own `strcat` that reallocates if the buffer isn't large enough? It's up to you.)